# Angle in altair chart title doesn't rotate by specified angle

Tags: python, altair

I would like to have a slanted title for my altair chart, and it seems that the functionality exists, but I haven't been able to figure out how it works. Here is a very simple example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{'description':'bar1','value':10},{'description':'bar2','value':12}])
alt.Chart(df,title="this is a very long title and I want it to be slanted 45 degrees",width=50)\
.mark_rect().encode(x='value',y='description').configure_title(angle=45)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this configuration setting is not working; it may be a bug in Vega or Vega-Lite. As a workaround, you can specify the title angle directly in the title properties:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df=pd.DataFrame([
  {'description':'bar1','value':10},
  {'description':'bar2','value':12}
])

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
  x='value',
  y='description'
).properties(
  title=alt.TitleParams(
    text="this is a very long title and I want it to be slanted 45 degrees",
    angle=45
  )
)
```

[image]